# coding autoresponder into phpmail

Tags: php

I've tried a few people's answer, none worked. I have a good working phpmail function, I just want to add an autorespond function to it, so that the sender can be immediately notified that submission was received.

My code is this:

```
    <?php
        $mail_to_send_to = "contact@matejkadesign.com";
        $your_feedbackmail = "form@matejkadesign.com";


        $sendflag = $_REQUEST['sendflag'];
        if ( $sendflag == "send" )
        {
                $name = $_REQUEST['name'] ;
                $email = $_REQUEST['email'] ;
                $message = $_REQUEST['message'] ;
                $headers = "From: $your_feedbackmail" . "\r\n" . "Reply-To: $name <$email>" . "\r\n" ;
                $a = mail( $mail_to_send_to, "Contact request", $message, $headers );
                if ($a) 
                {
                    print("Message sent, thank you! You can send another");
                } else {
                    print("Message wasn't sent, please check that your email was filled in properly");
                }
        }
?>
```

I want to say something like this in the autorespond:

```
Thank you for contacting us. This is an automatically generated reply confirming your submission. We will get back to you as soon as possible.

Sincerely,
John Doe
```

Answer (score 0):

It is not clearly what you want but I doing a wild guess. You want to e-mail the user when he/she used this form. Use this code:

```
<?php

$mail_to_send_to = "contact@matejkadesign.com";
$your_feedbackmail = "form@matejkadesign.com";


$sendflag = $_REQUEST['sendflag'];

if ( $sendflag == "send" ) {
    $name = $_REQUEST['name'] ;
    $email = $_REQUEST['email'] ;
    $message = $_REQUEST['message'] ;
    $headers = "From: $your_feedbackmail" . "\r\n" . "Reply-To: $name <$email>" . "\r\n" ;
    $a = mail( $mail_to_send_to, "Contact request", $message, $headers );
    if ($a) 
    {
        print("Message sent, thank you! You can send another");
        $message_back = "Thank you for contacting us. This is an automatically generated reply confirming your submission. We will get back to you as soon as possible.";
        mail( $email, "Contact request", $message_back, $headers );
    } else {
        print("Message wasn't sent, please check that your email was filled in properly");
    }
}

?>
```

Comment: Like the other answers I found in search, this code addition renders my whole webpage unreachable. If I add your code, the web browser can't access the form page and if I take it out, the browser can load it. Strange...any thoughts?